# Unable to launch Sahi Pro 5 on Windows 7 due to lack of valid license

Tags: windows-7, licensing, sahi

I have installed Sahi Pro 5 on Windows 7. After installing successfully I double click on "Sahi Pro" desktop icon. A command prompt and Sahi Dashboard was appeared. But a pop up was appeared asking to add license. So, I need to add license. Otherwise I am NOT able to launch Sahi Pro.

How can I add license?

[image: The pop up asked for adding license]

Comment: Is this a serious question ?

Comment: I don't know whether it is serious or not. But the problem is a blocker to me coz I'm unable to launch Sahi. HamZa DzCyberDeV: Do you know the solution? If yes, please provide me

Comment: Well have you purchased the software ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you download Sahi_pro. You should get one auto generated email with the Sahi_pro trial license of 1 month as the attachment (license.data file).
Download license.data into your file directory.

Click "Add License" button and browse to the license.data file.

option2.

Copy "license.data" into the Sahi_installed_directory/userdata/config folder and restart Sahi.

Comment: Thanks Kshitij Gupta. It's working well. After 1 month what to do?

Comment: If you want to buy the licenses, please do drop an email to "Support@sahi.co.in" with your requirement or any query about the licenses. One of the Sahi team member will reply you in one business working day.
Sahi team also helps for the demo or POC related queries about the product Sahi_pro.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. As I know Sahi is an open source. Why does it require to buy license?

Comment: Sahi open source is free. If you don't want to buy sahi_pro. You can go with Sahi OS.
You can go-through the following page to more details or to download Sahi OS "http://sahi.co.in/sahi-open-source/"

The link "http://sahi.co.in/sahi-pro/compare-sahi-os-and-sahi-pro/" will give you the comparison between Sahi_OS and Sahi_pro

Comment: Sahi OS has some limitations of features compared to Sahi Pro. Anyway, is there any option to extend the license after 1 month without buying Sahi Pro?

Comment: You can contact to "support@sahi.co.in"